# Is this sentence grammatically correct? "Where"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I would like to know if there is any grammatical error in this sentence. Especially, the last part of the sentence when using the word "where".

> All account types will be based on profiles, individual and entity profiles, where general profiles for each account are automatically created by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a well-formed sentence overall.  It's unclear whether "individual and entity profiles" are distinct from or a subset of "profiles".

However, the meaning of "where" in this sentence is similar to saying "the following is true of what was just mentioned", or "for the things previously described, the following applies".

For example... "All account types are based on profiles, individual and entity profiles.  The following is true regarding these things: general profiles for each account will be automatically created by default."

The clear advantage to using "where" is the brevity it provides.

I hope that helps.